# sizeof(array) / sizeof(int)

Tags: c, arrays, sizeof

Within a function I have declared an array:

```
int char_count_array[118] = {0};
```

Later on, I pass this array to a function and calculate the following:

```
int xx = sizeof(char_count_array); 
int xy = sizeof(char_count_array)/sizeof(int);
```

However, the result I get is: *xx = 4  xy = 1*

I thought I would be getting: *xx = 472(118 * 4)  xy = 118 (472 / 4)*.

Would anyone know what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: The variable you get on defining array is a pointer. You cannot get the size of an array from a pointer. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492384/how-to-find-the-sizeofa-pointer-pointing-to-an-array

Comment: dupe and flagged as such

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are passing it to a function, it's most likely going in as `int*` instead of `int[118]`.  So your `sizeof` is returning the size of a pointer.  When you pass C arrays to functions, it's conventional to also pass the number of elements.

```
my_func( arr, sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely when you are passing the array to function you are actually passing a `pointer` which has a size of `4` on your machine. If you need to know the size of the array you need to pass the size as another parameter to the function.